# a thread pool executor in java which allows only 10 thread as soon as 11th thread is submitted it will give exception saying maximum limit reached

Tags: java, multithreading

a thread pool executor in java which allows only 10 thread as soon as 11th thread is submitted it will give exception saying maximum limit reached

Can somebody help

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    executor.submit(new Processor(1));
    executor.submit(new Processor(2));
    executor.submit(new Processor(3));
    executor.submit(new Processor(4));

}
```

here it is wating not showing any exception

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the ThreadPoolExecutor properties like this -

`ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 0L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());`

Use SynchronousQueue which allows 0 queue size. So as soon as you submit 11th task the executor will reject the task as throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to stop you making your *own* class, which implements the `ExecutorService` interface and which contains a "real" executor (from `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`) as one of its members.

Then, most of *your* methods will simply pass the request onto your contained executor, after recording changes to the current statuses of the various threads.

However, in your `submit` methods, you could simply check if the capacity is full and throw your own exception. If it's *not* full, you could pass on the request as all the other methods.